# How to add two variable in jQuery if multiple rows are generated dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created a dynamic table where multiple rows are generate and inside each row I have a modal and form included inside the modal. where every modal form having unique id. Now I want to show the result of two variable inside the text field which is disabled. So, How can I do this ?Please help me.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = parseInt($('#unit_rate'+this.id).val());
    var b = parseInt($('#tax'+this.id).val());
    var total = a+b;
    $('#price').val(total);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="unit_rate" id="unit_rate<?php echo $product_id; ?>" value="">
<input type="text" name="tax" id="tax<?php echo $product_id; ?>" value="">
<input type="text" name="price" id="price<?php echo $product_id; ?>" value="">
```

Thank You

Comment: where is defined "id" in using this.id

Comment: The problem is `this.id` is `undefined`.

Comment: Given that `this` refers to the `window`, what are you expecting `this.id` to return?

Comment: are you using table to populate  rows?

Comment: id is generated dynamically. I have retrive it from the table

Comment: Yes, @Pratikrajethube

Comment: why dont you try  it by parsing document model. e.i :-get the table and then loop through its rows and just add first two cell and populate result in 3rd cell? if you want this kind of solution i can write .let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rows are dynamically generated so they are not part of **DOM** when the page is loaded. To select a specific row use `document.getElementById`:

Here is a simple Demo:

```js
var id=1;
$("body").append('<input type="text" name="unit_rate" id="unit_rate1" value=""><input type="text" name="tax" id="tax1" value=""><input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="">');

$("button").on("click",function(){
    var a = parseInt($(document.getElementById('unit_rate'+id)).val());
    var b = parseInt($(document.getElementById('tax'+id)).val());
    var total = a+b;
    console.log(total);
    $(document.getElementById('price')).val(total);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button typ="button" >Sum</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would assign a single class to all elements you want to get the values from (this won't be generated dynamically).
Then you can select all those elements - $(".my_class_here") - and iterate through your selection with $.each(), reading the values and adding them up.

Following your example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var total=0;
    var elements = $(".test");
    $.each(elements, function( key, value ) {
        total += parseInt(value.value, 10);
    });
    $('#price').val(total);
});

<input type="text" name="unit_rate" id="unit_rate1" class="test" value="20"><br>
<input type="text" name="tax" id="tax2" class="test" value="50"><br>
<input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="">
```

Bear in mind, that jQuery is returning the HTML objects, so we need to use `.value` instead of `.val()` to get the number. Also, since you used text inputs, we need to use `parseInt()` to get the actual number instead of string from the field.